# How to specify the css property text-fill-color in IE and Mozilla (as I did -webkit-text-fill-color for webkit)

Tags: html, css

In chrome the color is showing, but in IE, FF how do I use this property

**CSS**

```
#Grid td.note div.has-note i {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #b4efa8;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK `text-fill-color` is a non-standard, webkit only property. There is no equivalent in other browsers. But, as this property simply overrules the standard `color` property, you can just add `color: #b4efa8;` as a fall back

Answer (score 3):

In Firefox and IE you do not have `text-fill-color` property.Use Color instead of text-fill-color.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK `text-fill-color` is a non-standard, webkit only property . There is no equivalent in other browsers (maybe somebody can correct me?).

But, as this property simply overrules the standard color property, you can just add the standard `color` property as a fallback...

```
#Grid td.note div.has-note i {
  color: red; /* all browsers */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #b4efa8; /* webkit browsers only */
}
```

```css
div {
  color: red; /* all browsers */
  -webkit-text-fill-color: blue; /* webkit browsers only */
}
```

```html
<div>
  What colour am I?
</div>
```

Comment: maybe it is only useful if we need different color in webkit browsers

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS
Only webkit browsers have `text-fill-color` property othes have only `color` property

```
#Grid td.note div.has-note i {
  -webkit-text-fill-color: #b4efa8;
  color: #b4fa8;
}
```

Comment: Add explanation why do we need those two properties

Comment: I have chat icon in table columns. When I clicked on icon showing one text area dynamically and enter any thing into that then I want differentiate the with other columns which have edited.

Comment: then use diffrent colors

Answer (score 1):

It can be used to work with cursor color. See the snippet...

```css
textarea { display: block; width:100%; height: 5em; } /* Unimportant */ 

#t1 { color:  #ff0000; }
#t2 { color:  #ff0000; -webkit-text-fill-color: #0000ff; }
```

```html
<textarea id="t1">I'm all RED ! Both text and cursor.</textarea>  
<textarea id="t2">My cursor is RED because of "color:", but my font face is BLUE because of "-webkit-text-fill-color:". I work only in Opera, Chrome, and should start working in new Firefox (v.48) by next month :) ...</textarea>
```

For example w3schools.com use this in their on-line example editor to make highlighting of the code possible. Since text in  can't be formatted, they made it transparent using "-webkit-text-fill-color" but kept the cursor, then they clone the code into underlying div and color it.